# Mask the font container without wrapping text in react-native

Tags: react-native

The question is I want a container filled with images and multiple texts... I want to animate the scale of the container with gesture. The problem I see is when the container transforms the text wraps... how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<backgourndImage> </backgroundImage>` in react react where you can wrap views, and text are the area you want.

Comment: Image is not a problem but the Text component wraps when the parent container's width is transformed. Let me explain better, I am trying to use pan gesture to transform a box and the box should change its width along... Now the text contents are wrapping when the box is transformed. I want to avoid this and mask the contents as the box shrinks in width. is this making sense ?

Comment: @Kris, you can add opacity animation to the text.

Comment: Opacity will not solve because users will notice the wrapping text before the opacity hits 0. If we make the opacity transition too quick then the container looks empty very early

Comment: @Kris, sorry, but I can't understand what do you mean 'I see is when the container transforms the text wraps'. Text width longer than container?